# VBS Script passing argument?

Tags: scripting, windows-command-prompt, vbscript

Hello everyone I have this script in VBS:

```
    On Error Resume Next

If WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
     WScript.Echo "This script requires arguments."
     WScript.Quit
End If

Dim sURL, sAuth, sRequestType
sUrl = "http://192.168.10.6:8080/rest/servicedeskapi/request"
sAuth = "YWRtafW5pc3dRyYXRvcjdddpQdW50bs0dUMyE="
sRequestType = "POST"

Dim sArg1, sArg2, sArg3, sBody

sBody = "{""serviceDeskId"":2,""requestTypeId"":30,""requestFieldValues"":{""summary"":""sArg1"",""description"":""sArg2""}}"

sResponse = HTTPPost(sURL, sBody)
WScript.Echo sResponse

Function HTTPPost(sURL, sRequest)
  Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  oHTTP.open sRequestType, sURL, false
  oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
  oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sRequest)
  oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & sAuth
  oHTTP.send sRequest
  HTTPPost = oHTTP.responseText
End Function
```

Everything seems to work fine expect the variables that i pass in the command line "sArg1, sArg2 and sArg3" get passed as exact text instead of variables, I have had this working on the past but I don't remember what I did to fix it.

csript.exe c:\folder\script.vbs testsarg1 testsarg2 testsarg3

Anything see anything wrong? I have tried playing around with "" around the args but that doesn't seem to help.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you assigning your command line arguments to the variables you declared?

```
Dim sArg1, sArg2, sArg3, sBody
```

You have to retrieve and assign the variables.

```
Dim sArg1, sArg2, sArg3, sBody
sArg1 = Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
sArg2 = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)
sArg3 = Wscript.Arguments.Item(2)
wscript.Echo "sArg1 = " + sArg1 + "; sArg2 = " + sArg2 + "; sArg3 = " + sArg3
```

You don't even have to declare them first if you don't want to.

Comment: Thanks man, that fixed it after i wrapped the variables in 3x ".